# How to find if all dates in a array are lesser than current date using loopback 3 filters?

Tags: javascript, loopback

I have an object in my databank which has a array of blocked dates, and I want to create a loopback filter function which retrieves the instances that have expired all their values (IE: all values are lesser than the current date).

I have tried the following query, but it didn't work:

```
const query = {
    where: {
        blockedDates: {
            nin: [
                { lt: date }
            ]
        }
    },
    fields: "id"
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a dummy data of your collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For date filtering, inside where you can pass object with `lt` or `gt` defined. For example:

```
const query = {
    where: {
        blockedDates: {lt: Date.now()}
    }
}
```